# How to handle SAP Kapsel Offline app OData conflicts properly?

Tags: cordova-plugins, sapui5, sap-smp

I build an app that is able to store OData offline by using SAP Kapsel Plugins.
More or less it's the same as generated by WEB ID or similer to the apps in this example: https://blogs.sap.com/2017/01/24/getting-started-with-kapsel-part-10-offline-odatasp13/

Now I am at the point to check the error resolution potential. I created a sync conflict (chaning data on the server after the offline database was stored and changed something on the app and started a flush).

As mentioned in the documentation I can see the error in ErrorArchive and could also see some details. But what I am missing is the information of the "current" data on the database.

In the error details I can just see the data on the device but not the data changed on the server.

For example:

1. Device is loading some names into offline store
2. Device is offline
3. User A is changing some names
4. User B is changing one of this names directly online
5. User A is online again and starts a sync
6. User A is now informend about the entity that was changed BUT:

   - not the content user B entered

I just see the "offline" data.

Is there a solution to see the "current" and the "offline" one in a kind of compare view?

Please also note that the server communication is done by the Kapsel Plugin and not with normal AJAX calls. This could be an alternative but I am wondering if there is no smarter way supported by the API?

Meanwhile I figured out how to load the online data (manually).
This could be done by switching http handler back to normal one.

```
sap.OData.removeHttpClient();
sap.OData.applyHttpClient();
```

Anyhow this does not look like a proper solution and I also have the issue with the conflict log itself. It must be deleted before any refresh could be applied.

I could not find any proper documentation for that. Also ETag handling is hardly described in SAPUI5 and SAP Kapsel documentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default solution is that SMP or HCPms is detecting errors by ETags. At client side there is no API to manipulate ETags in case of conflicts. A potential solution to implement a kind of diff view on the device would work like this:

1. Show errors
2. Cache errors (maybe only in memory?)
3. delete the errors
4. do a refresh of the database
5. build a diff view with current data and cached errors

The idea with

```
sap.OData.removeHttpClient();
sap.OData.applyHttpClient();
```

could also work but could be very tricky and may introduce side effects.
Maybe some requests are triggered against the "wrong" backend.

Comment: Downvoting because the answer is a suggestion of a hacky workaround at best, but really fails to identify the underlying issue. It should not have been accepted.

Answer (score 2):

This question is a really tricky one, due to its implications. I understand that you are simulating a synchronization error due to concurrent modification, and want to know if there is a way for the client to obtain the "current" server state in order to give the user a means to compare the local and server state.

First, let me give you the short answer: No, there is no way for the client to see the current server state "for reference" via the Offline APIs when there are synchronization errors. Doing an online query as outlined above *might* work, but it certainly is a bad idea.

Now for the longer answer, which explains why this is not necessarily a defect and why I said there are quite some implications to the answer.

## Types of Synchronization Errors

[We distinguish a number of synchronization errors](http://help-legacy.sap.com/saphelp_smp3013sdk/helpdata/en/e5/033aa25c67486ab06505f565bf6f9f/content.htm), and in this context, we are clearly dealing with business-related issues. There are two subtypes here: Those that the user can correct, e.g. validation errors, and those that are issues in the business process itself.

If the user violates the input range, e.g. by putting a negative price for a product, the server would reply with the corresponding message: "-1 is not a valid input value for 'Price'". You, as a developer, can display such messages to the user from the error archive, and the ensuing fix is indeed a very easy one.

Now when we talk about concurrent modification, things get really, really nasty. In fact, I like to say that in this case there is an issue with the business process, because on one hand, we allow data to get out of sync. On the other hand, the process allows multiple users to manipulate the same piece of information. How all relevant users should now be notified and synchronize, is no longer just a technical detail, but in fact a new business process. There just is no way to generically device how to handle this case. In most cases, it would involve back-office experts who need to decide how the changes should be merged.

## A Better Solution

Angstrom pointed out that there is no way to manipulate ETags on the client side, and you should in fact not even think about it. ETags work like version numbers in optimistic locking scenarios, and changing the ETag basically means "Just overwrite what's on the server". This is a no-go in serious scenarios.

An *acceptable* workaround would be the following:

1. Make sure the server returns verbose error messages so that the user can see what happened and what caused the conflict.
2. If that does not help, refresh the data. This will get you an updated ETag, and merge the local changes into the "current" server state, but only locally. "Merging" really means that local changes always overwrite remote changes.
3. The user now has another opportunity to review the data and can submit it again.

## A Good Solution

Better is not necessarily good, so here is what you should really do: **Never let concurrent modification happen because it is really expensive to handle.** This implies that not the developer should address this issue, but the business needs to change the process.

The right question to ask is, "When you replicate data in a distributed system, why do you allow it to be modified concurrently at all?" Typically stakeholders will not like this kind of question, and the appropriate reaction is to work out a conflict resolution process together with them. Only then they will realize how expensive fixing that kind of desynchronization is, and more often than not they will see that adjusting the process is way cheaper than insisting in yet another back-office process to fix the issues it causes. Even if they insist that there is a need for this concurrent modification, they will now understand that it is not your task to sort this out and that they need to invest in a conflict resolution process.

## TL;DR

There is no way to compare the server and client state to the server state on the client, but you can do a refresh to retain the local changes and get an updated ETag. The real solution, however, is to rework the business process, because this no longer is a purely technical issue.

Comment: Hello Michael, good explanation, it describse exactly my issue. Anyhow my question was more about the technical possibilities :) Indeed I was already pushing to avoid conflicts :)

Comment: @user3783327 In that case I think what you want is option #2 - refresh the local data in order to obtain a new ETag, and your users get to keep their local changes, while the remaining properties are updated.

Comment: I'm curious to know how creates are handled. E.g. if you create a new record offline does it assign a new unique primary key? If so what happens to when back online and the said primary key has already been taken ?

Comment: @AdamHarkus sorry, I must have missed the notification. If I am not mistaken, by default the framework generates temporary technical keys which are substituted with what the backend returns after synchronization, since usually we see backend-generated keys. You can also provide your own key when you create an instance, though, if the backend doesn't do it for you.